# Backspace в консоли

Tags: c

Как воспроизвести Backspace в консоли ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        if (c == '\t')
            printf("\\t");

        if (c == '\b')
            printf("\\b");

        if (c == '\\')
            printf("\\\\");

            putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: С помощью  [stty](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) замените символ ERASE

Answer (score 1):

Ты просто забыл `else`, поэтому выводится лишнее. Надо так: https://ideone.com/5yAcwi

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int ch;

  while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF)
    switch (ch)
    {
      case '\t':   putchar('\\');   putchar('t');    break;
      case '\\':   putchar('\\');   putchar('\\');   break;
      case '\b':   putchar('\\');   putchar('b');    break;
      default:     putchar(ch);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

> Как воспроизвести Backspace в консоли ?

Ну на ideone используется перенаправление ввода из файла и, как видно, код работает ожидаемым образом. Честно говоря, у меня возникали сомнения, должен ли он работать с нормальной консолью, но ведь программа не различает источники? Получается, обычный <kbd>backspace</kbd> должен работать. Если нет, то используй перенаправление ввода.

Comment: На данном этапе упражнений, мне неизвестны switch, case, default, else, break....

Comment: В твою программу можно добавить else в 3 места. Обычно его изучают вместе с if.